# How can I connect 2 devices that are in different location using sockaddr

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I've written 2 quicks programs just for learning purposes: Client.c and Server.c. The functionality consist in a text-chatting by turns (firstly, Client.c send a message to Server.c and then vice versa).
This is Client.c code (I used TCP Protocol):

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){

int cd;
struct sockaddr_in ssock, csock;
char buff[30];
char recbuff[60];
char inip[15];
write(1,"Escriba la ip del servidor: \n\0",30);
read(0,inip,15);
cd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
memset((struct sockaddr *)&ssock,0,sizeof(ssock));

ssock.sin_family=AF_INET;
ssock.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(inip);
ssock.sin_port=htons(8000);
int x=connect(cd,(struct sockaddr *) &ssock, sizeof(ssock));
perror("connect()");

while(1){
        read(0,buff,30);
        send(cd,buff,20,0);
        if(recv(cd,recbuff,60,0)>0)
        printf("%s\n",recbuff);
}
}
```

And this is the Server.c code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv){
struct sockaddr_in sock, client_sock;
int n,sd,cd;
char buff[30];
char recbuff[30];
sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
memset((char *)&sock,0,sizeof(sock));
sock.sin_family=AF_INET;
sock.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
sock.sin_port=htons(8000);
bind (sd,(struct sockaddr *)&sock,sizeof(sock));
struct ifaddrs *ifa;
struct sockaddr_in *sa;
char *addr;
getifaddrs(&ifa);
for (ifa = ifa; ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {

        if (ifa->ifa_addr && ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET) {
                sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) ifa->ifa_addr;
                addr = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
                printf("Interface: %s\tAddress: %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addr);
        }
}
    freeifaddrs(ifa);
listen(sd,1);
int size=sizeof(client_sock);
cd=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_sock,&size);
char * ip = inet_ntoa(client_sock.sin_addr);
printf("conexión aceptada: %s\n", ip);
int i=0;
while(1){
if(recv(cd,recbuff,30,0)>0)
printf("%s\n",recbuff);
read(0,buff,30);
send(cd,buff,60,0);
}
}
```

It works perfectly with 2 devices on the same router but if the other device is connected to different router then messages can't reach it.
I deduced that the problem is the Ip I introduced in Client.c.
When both devices are on different router I guess I need a public Ip to be able to reach it so I want to introduce the public Ip of the Server.c, then his private Ip and finally his port right?
Can anyone give me any hint of how can I make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. Just give the server's public IP to the client. Make sure no firewalls are blocking connection. And you're pretty much set

Comment: You can use a tool like wireshark to see what happens on the network.

Comment: This is not really a programming question but rather a networking question. If you can ping between the devices then the same addresses in the code will work. So you don't need to write any code to get the networking set up correctly first.

Comment: You are using AF_INET, not AF_UNIX, which means that your [tag:unix-sockets] tag is irrelevant.

Comment: All broken anyway, for two of the usual three reasons, (syscall returns incompletely handled, misuse of C lib calls that require NUL-terminated char arrays).